# How can I "really" understand processes and threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process

I am trying to "really" understand processes & threads - I have read books and articles about them, but something always seems missing with the overall picture. Sure, I can rattle on about details such as how each process has it's own memory space and how threads belonging to the same process share the same memory space etc but I am looking for things from an OS & memory perspective I guess - things such as:

1. How to spawn them & what exactly happens in memory.
2. What happens during IPCs, and inter-thread communications.
3. How they are handled on a multi-core system.
4. How is context determined in code? (i.e, how a function belongs to a process/ a thread). {Hope this is clear!!!!}

All this with simple code examples would be fantastic.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A process encapsulate code with all ressources (memory, open files, shared memory) necessary to execute it. A thread is just an execution in a process, that means roughly a pointer on current instruction of the thread and a call stack. A process contains at least one thread, but you may have several threads in a single process.

1. spawning a process is a matter of OS, this could be very different. Unix traditionally provides `fork` that permits a process to clone itself (almost everything is duplicate). spawning a thread is both a matter of language and OS (there exists a mapping from language threads to OS threads). C API contains `pthread_create` that just allocates a new stack for it a initialize the instruction pointer to the address of some function to run.
2. There is nothing special... Inter-thread communication is very easy because they share the same address space, but beware that concurrency is a problem.
3. Everything is possible: from one process and all its threads on the same core, to threads distributed over the set of cores and be moved along the run.
4. There is no function that belong to a thread. A thread begins by executing some function and terminates when its call stack is empty (returning from this initial call).